# unable to load resource (icons) using .css file for JSF page

Tags: css, jsf-2.2

This is my `icon.css` file.

```
 @font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:url("#resource{['css/fonts/icomoon.eot']}");
src:url("#resource{['css/fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix']}") format('embedded-opentype'),
    url("#resource{['css/fonts/icomoon.woff']}") format('woff'),
    url("#resource{['css/fonts/icomoon.ttf']}") format('truetype'),
    url("#resource{['css/fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon']}") format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

I have used resource handler instead I need to use resource loader to call `.eot` , `.woff` files. because my icons are not displaying on my jsf page.
I have googled about the same but couldn't find the solution. 
I would be thankful if anyone can help me.

Comment: Answer depends on how exactly you're importing this resource via `<h:outputStylesheet>`. Tarik's answer assumes that you apparently (and incorrectly!) used `library="css" name="..."` instead of `name="css/..."`.

Comment: @BlackBird As per BalusC's comments, I deleted my question as it's misleading and I used a wrong approach. Anyway, could you include in your question how you are importing CSS in your xhtml page ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src: url("#{resource['Styles:fonts/icomoon.eot?gmqg4d']}");
src: url("#{resource['Styles:fonts/icomoon.eot']}&gmqg4d#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
url("#{resource['Styles:fonts/icomoon.ttf']}") format('truetype'),
url("#{resource['Styles:fonts/icomoon.woff']}") format('woff'),
url("#{resource['Styles:fonts/icomoon.svg']}&gmqg4d#icomoon") format('svg'); 
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Here the code.
Look, if it does not work, restart the server as many times as necessary until the icons appear